# Catching exceptions in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, exception

Is there some sort of try/catch function in obj-c? I'm trying to load saved files from an array and would like to have some sort of message popping up instead of the app crashing in case the array is empty. Whats the best and optimal way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@try {
    //Code
} 
@catch (id theException) {
    //Code
} 
@finally {
    //Code
}
```

Or you can test if the array is empty ...

Comment: +1 because you answered the question and also put the right thing to do in at the end.

Comment: So I just have to do an if(someArray == nil) {//do something } logic?

Comment: yep. You can also test if there is items in your array I don't know what you are doing after : if(someArray == nil || [someArray count] == 0) { // handle the empty array }

Comment: Exceptions in Objective-C are for programmer errors, not errors that can be expected to crop up in normal use. Try to avoid the `@try/@catch` block if possible. Testing the array is a much better approach in this case.

Comment: Ah right. I totally forgot about the count parameter. I just want to mail the files and of course it crashes if the array is empty and the 'exception' is not handled. Thank you.